# data.table column number in .SDcols

Tags: r, data.table

I want to exponentiate every column specified in .SDcols, by the column number of every column, is that possible?

I think it's possible if one can get information about the columns like col number.

Answer (score 6):

We can use `Map` to do this.  Suppose, if we are changing the first and second columns ('i1'), specify it in the `.SDcols`, and with `Map` we apply the function on each column of Subset of Data.table (`.SD`) with the corresponding index specified in 'i1' and assign (`:=`) the output to the columns.

```
i1 <- 1:2
dt1[, (i1) := Map(`^`, .SD, i1), .SDcols = i1]
```

#### data

```
dt1 <- data.table(a = 1:5, b= 6:10, c = 11:15)
```